# Error en la aplicación "Excepción no controlada"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net

Buen dia.
Actualmente tengo un programa en C#, para gestión de información.
Este funciona sin problema cuando lo ejecuto de forma local, se realizan todas las operaciones sin problema.
Este proceso lo debo ejecutar cada 3 mins, por lo cual estoy generado una tarea programada, pero al ejecutarse tengo el siguiente error.

[image: ERROR]

Probe modificar la ruta de el archivo que no encuentra, (cargas.json), en diferentes posiciones, raíces etc y no es posible que este se ejecute como tarea programada.

¿Que podría revisar? O que alternativa podría usar para ejecutar este, muchas gracias.

Comment: Dice que el archivo no encontrado es credentials.json, no cargas.json

Comment: Hola, he asegurado todos estos archivos, incluso el programa corre sin lío cuando lo ejecuto manual, el error solo es desde el programador de tareas. Gracias